# CassandraRowWriteAheadSink uses milliseconds for timestamp instead of microseconds

Tags: apache-flink

I have a flink job implementation that uses both Cassandra driver (com.datastax.driver) and Cassandra-Flink connector. In a special situation where persistence needs to be blocking (on start-up) Cassandra driver is used and in all other cases [CassandraRowWriteAheadSink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/cassandra/CassandraRowWriteAheadSink.html) is used. But in Cassandra driver each mutation has a **microsecond-precision timestamp**, which is used to order operations relative to each other while when cassandra-flink connector is used the [GenericWriteAheadSink](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/operators/GenericWriteAheadSink.java#L164) uses precision in **millisecond** (because the context.getCheckpointTimestamp() is used) and this introduces problems. We overrode this behavior, but is there a better way to handle this case?